# Create horizontally and vertically scrollable table inside Terminal application with Python Urwid/NCurses

Tags: python, ncurses, urwid

I want to create a Terminal application which displays a table with lots of columns and rows (not fitting on a regular screen in width and height). 
The user should be able to scroll across the table horizontally *and* vertically (and the rows should be selectable), so it behaves a bit like htop.

I could not find any hint how to create such a widget with urwid, most examples wrap text and don't allow scrolling horizontally.

What are the urwid widgets/containers that I have to use to realize this behavior?
Any good example out there which does something similar? 
I'm fine with using the latest version of Urwid

**EDIT**:
since urwid does not provide horizontally-scrollable listsboxes, can I at least create such a functionality with Python-ncurses?

Answer (score 4):

Ncurses has the concept of a "pad".  A pad is like a window but may be bigger than the screen.  You can then display a small part of the pad on the screen. see the python [curses.newpad](http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html#curses.newpad) documentation.

However, since the pad is low level construct you will need to build all the display and navigation stuff around it.

Answer (score 0):

Python-urwid does not support horizontally scrollable ListBoxes yet (afaik that is what I need), this is the corresponding ticket:

http://excess.org/urwid/ticket/9